# Updating table from async task android

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm following [this tutorial](http://huuah.com/android-progress-bar-and-thread-updating/)
to learn how to make progress bars. I'm trying to show the progress bar on top of my activity and have it update the activity's table view in the background.

So I created an async task for the dialog that takes a callback:

```
package com.lib.bookworm;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;



public class UIThreadProgress extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private UIThreadCallback callback = null;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    private int maxValue = 100, incAmount = 1;
    private Context context = null;
    
    public UIThreadProgress(Context context, UIThreadCallback callback) {
        this.context = context;
        this.callback = callback;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
        while(this.callback.condition()) {
            this.callback.run();
            this.publishProgress();
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        dialog.incrementProgressBy(incAmount);
    };
    
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog.setProgress(0);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setMax(maxValue);
        dialog.show();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
        this.callback.onThreadFinish();
    }
    
}
```

---

**In My Activity:**

```
final String page = htmlPage.substring(start, end).trim();

//Create new instance of the AsyncTask..

new UIThreadProgress(this, new UIThreadCallback() {
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        row_id = makeTableRow(row_id, layout, params, matcher); //ADD a row to the table layout.
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onThreadFinish() {
        System.out.println("FINISHED!!");                       
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean condition() {
        return matcher.find();
    }
}).execute();
```

So the above creates an async task to run to update a table layout activity while showing the progress bar that displays how much work has been done..

However, I get an error saying that only the thread that started the activity can update its views. I tried changing my Async Task's run to the following:

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        row_id = makeTableRow(row_id, layout, params, matcher); //ADD a row to the table layout.
    }
}
```

But this gives me synchronization errors.. Any ideas how I can display progress and at the same time update my table in the background?

Currently my UI looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever update that you are doing in the UI do it in progress update, use `Global Variables` to pass values or use `Getter Setter`.

Here is a simple example, from one of my current project.
It changes the width of the LinearLayout, which acts as progress bar and also updates the textview with `X%`. Am updating by calling `onProgressUpdate`

```
    public class Updater extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        Log.wtf(tag, "width" + width);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        while (updated < sleep) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(updateEveryXmillSec);
                updated = updated + updateEveryXmillSec;
                publishProgress();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        mTextView.setText((int) (100 * updated / sleep) + " %");
        xwidth = (width * ((int) (100 * updated / sleep)) / 100);
        mLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(xwidth,
                height));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class));
        finish();

    }
}
```

Call `new Updater().execute();` to trigger the action.

Answer (score 0):

You should split your UI data from the Row Data. Make a RowObject which contains the data to display in the table:

```
class RowData {
    String program;
    String course;
    String bookName;

    // get/set etc
}
```

You can fill this object in the UIThreadProgress class run method and push it to a synced list.

In onProcessUpdate() you can than build the View Object based on the synced list and add it to the View Hierachie. You are on the UI thread now, and adding should be possible.

You have to care about a synced list during this. Because the Background Thread and the UI Thread will adding and removing objects at the same time. a synchronized will help here. Depending on the speed of your algorithm to calculate the needed data, a faster approach than the synced list is better. But the Idea is always the same. You have to split your data and the View Operations.